# How to use .properties in a Spring Validation annotation

Tags: spring-validator

I have the following annotation

```
@Size(min=5,message="{error.address1.null}")
```

and the following in my properties

```
#Error Messages
error.address1.null = Address is required
```

and the following jsp

```
<form:errors path="addressLine1" cssClass="error" />
```

But I see

```
{error.address1.null}
```

Do i have to wire something? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly easy

```
@Size(min=5)
```

properties

```
Size.class.getterSetter = message
```

Not sure how this will work for multiple annotations in Java8